# Neo4j Query Browser does not show actual syntax error in RC1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just migrated from M06 TO RC1, and now I see that the cypher query window no longer shows the actual error — instead it just returns "Unknown Error" as shown in the image below.

[image: Error Message from RC1 upgrade]

But the same query on the M06 returns more information which is very useful for some one like me who is still learning this.

[image: Error message as in M06]

Is there some setting I am missing to let the neo4j expose the actual error in neo4j properties?

Comment: I noticed the same thing and figured it's a bug.

Comment: M06 has this one too - hit it a few times.

Comment: Just installed Neo4j Community 2.0.0-RCA and thought this was a limitation of the browser. I get this with every malformed query.

Comment: Should work with 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

This was a documented bug in Neo4j 2.0 RC1 (Release Candidate 1). Please update to the latest version of Neo4j -- version 2.0 GA (General Availability) from http://neo4j.org/download.

This bug is specific to 2.0 RC1 and was fixed prior to the release of 2.0 GA.